# sql-xml: select nodes collection

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 which has a xml column.

Here is a sample of the xml document in it:

```
<ROOT>
  <SITE_CHAR>
    <SITE_NAME>ScrivaniaEle</SITE_NAME>
    <SITE_RESPONSIBLE>database</SITE_RESPONSIBLE>
    <SITE_IGBP>URB</SITE_IGBP>
    <SITE_LAT>42.42716</SITE_LAT>
    <SITE_LON>12.09358</SITE_LON>
    <ELEVATION>323</ELEVATION>
  </SITE_CHAR>
  <SPP_O>
    <VALUE>BRNA</VALUE>
    <SPP_DATE>20090409</SPP_DATE>
  </SPP_O>
  <SPP_O>
    <VALUE>HEAN3</VALUE>
    <SPP_DATE>20090409</SPP_DATE>
  </SPP_O>
  <SPP_O>
    <VALUE>TRIN3   </VALUE>
    <SPP_DATE>20091111</SPP_DATE>
  </SPP_O>
  <SPP_U>
    <VALUE>HEAN3</VALUE>
    <SPP_DATE>20090409</SPP_DATE>
  </SPP_U>
  <SPP_U>
    <VALUE>TRIN3   </VALUE>
    <SPP_DATE>20091111</SPP_DATE>
  </SPP_U>
  <LAI>
    <VALUE>0.35863933908505</VALUE>
    <LAI_DATE>20080319</LAI_DATE>
    <LAI_COMMENT>"number of samples: 14"</LAI_COMMENT>
    <LAI_TECHNIQUE>"ACUPAR"</LAI_TECHNIQUE>
  </LAI>
</ROOT>
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to select only the first child nodes and only once; that is, I would like to retrieve the values `SITE_CHAR, SPP_O, LAI` and so on, once, independently from the values of the child nodes and from the inner attributes.

thanx in advance

Comment: Have a look [Simple Example of Reading XML File Using T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    NodeName = XmlRoot.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY 
    XmlContent.nodes('/ROOT/*') AS Tbl(XmlRoot)
```

[See this SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cdf9/1) for a full example.